# numpy style which is preferred? array.T[x] or array[:,0]

Tags: python, numpy

What is the preferred way to extract a column of data in numpy?

```
array[:,x]
```

or

```
array.T[x]
```

I find that having an array of data with the fields along the rows and data in columns is cleaner to manipulate in numpy:

```
array[x]
```

to get a whole series along one variable as opposed to the above options.
But having variables ordered by column is the standard file format.

Any preferences as to what is the easiest way to work with the data?

Should I transpose all my data when I read it in and then transpose again when I output?

Comment: sure why not...? the preferred method is the one that works best for you ...

Comment: Just wondering what other people do. Also because... "There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.
Although that way may not be obvious at first unless you're Dutch."

Comment: I can't think of a problem with `array.T[x]`, but it is not commonly used.  It isn't easily generalized to more dimensions.

Comment: `array[:,x]` seems harder to mis-intepret.

Comment: I am in favor of solutions that are generalizable so my favor goes to `array[:,x]` thank you.

Comment: So obviously I am new to stackexchange but why didn't you write those as answers? It seems comments are for clarification requests more.

Comment: Both options yield the same result, so none of them is write or wrong... You are rather asking for opinions than solutions, therefore we can rather comment than answer. My preference is `array[:,x]`.

Comment: What is a little off in your examples is your use of `x` for indices. Otherwise both options are OK, although people reading your code will better understand `[:, slice]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should prefer slicing `[:, x]`, for several reasons:

1. It is *faster*, probably because you are not transposing the *entire array* to extract a piece from it. Tested in Python 3.5.1, NumPy 1.11.0:

   ```
   >>> timeit.timeit('A[:,568]', setup = 'import numpy as np\nA = np.random.uniform(size=(1000,1000))')
   0.21135332298581488
   >>> timeit.timeit('A.T[568]', setup = 'import numpy as np\nA = np.random.uniform(size=(1000,1000))')
   0.3025632489880081
   ```
2. It generalizes in a straightforward way to higher dimensional arrays, like `A[3, :, 4]`
3. It reflects the NumPy way of thinking of arrays as multidimensional objects, rather than lists of lists (of lists).